# issue using C# to consume web service with enum type

Tags: c#, enums

I'm having an issue consuming a web service and hoped someone could shed some light.

I have everything I need working with the exception of an enum.

Generated Reference.cs contains:

```
public enum SearchType {
    sales,
    lettings,
}
```

My controller method has the following:

```
if (model.ValuationType == "lettings")
{
    Debug.WriteLine("in the lettings route");
    request = new ValuationRequest
    {
        ValuationType = SearchType.lettings,
        Postcode = model.Postcode,
        FromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
        ToDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14)
    };
}
else 
{
    Debug.WriteLine("in the sales route");
    request = new ValuationRequest
    {
        ValuationType = SearchType.sales,
        Postcode = model.Postcode,
        FromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
        ToDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14)
    };
}

var valuationAppointments = 
WebUtility.GetValuationAppointments(request);
```

and within `GetValuationAppointments` the utility simply does the following:

```
public static Appointment[] GetValuationAppointments(ValuationRequest request)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(request.ValuationType);
    Debug.WriteLine(request.Postcode);
    Debug.WriteLine(request.FromDate);
    Debug.WriteLine(request.ToDate);

    service = new MyWebService();
    var valuationAppointments = service.GetValuationAppointments(request);
    return valuationAppointments;
}
```

Now the debug from those write lines is showing everything exactly as I would have expected and returns appointments correctly, however, they are always sales. Even if lettings is passed through from the model to the service. My guess is something about the enum type is being completely ignored and so the service is defaulting to sales.

Visual Studio shows no warnings about `ValuationType = SearchType.lettings` and anything else I try with that line throws errors.

Any ideas at all why this `ValuationType = SearchType.lettings` is the only field failing?

evidence from debug:

```
in the lettings route
lettings
GU4 7QG
29/08/2018 10:47:21
11/09/2018 10:47:21
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: what does your `model` class look like?

Comment: use `if (model.ValuationType == SearchType.lettings)` instead of `if (model.ValuationType == "lettings")`

Comment: Alex, model class has         
    public Appointment[] ValuationAppointments { get; set; }

ershoaib, why?  The issue isn't that we're going into the wrong part of the if statement. I'm checking the model value is "lettings" then setting the ValuationRequest ValuationType to be SearchType.lettings.

Comment: is your `ValuationType` property in model is of type `string` or enum `SearchType`. If its string then change it to enum and then try once

Comment: Maybe it's not clear from the shortened code above, but the initial model, ValuationType is a string. That's ValuationModel.  However the "request" being created in the function above is using "ValuationRequest" which is different. In there it's an enum type. that's why I'm trying to hard code the new ValuationRequest ValuationType to SearchType.lettings as it is in the enum.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I wasn't specifying some mandatory field

```
SearchTypeSpecified = true;
```

fixed the issue!

Cheers all the same folks.